# How can I run my existing .NET WPF app in an arbitrary browser without a Silverlight plugin or .NET runtime?

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax, silverlight

I have an existing Microsoft .NET WPF app and want to have it run in the user's browser directly with no Silverlight plugins, no .NET runtime installed, etc.  I want straight, pure HTML, CSS and Javascript.  Ideally it can run in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, iOS and other browsers on any platform that supports Javascript.

Is there some technology (from Microsoft or others) that lets you take an existing .NET application and compile it to use HTML, CSS and Javascript and run in a browser with no plugins?

Comment: What do you mean by "Microsoft .NET app"?  Windows forms, WPF, Silverlight?

Comment: I have seen that Microsoft Office Live ([link](http://www.officelive.com)) is entirely written in HTML, CSS and Javascript, and others have suggested that they may have done this conversion manually.  If I were charged with making that product, I would certainly look at automating the conversion of as much as possible, so I am hoping they created some technology for it.

Comment: I should also add that converting it to use HTML5 canvas tag instead of HTML and CSS would be acceptable too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at ScriptSharp:

http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp

Although I'd be **very** surprised if you could just take an arbitrary .NET app and run it in the browser as Javascript. But you should be able to carry over business logic written in C# for the most part if it's separate from the presentation layer (the UI).

Comment: Thanks Julian.  I had seen ScriptSharp, but I had the same understanding as you that it would not handle the UI.  Porting the business logic would certainly be a big step in the right direction anyway.  I've seen frameworks like Cappuccino that allow you to create both desktop and browser-based apps from the same source code, although in the case of Cappuccino, their Objective-J language is a superset of Javascript to start with, which makes it rather easy.